# Where do Dispatch Group commands go in code?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to run a function X times in a for in loop but when all the functions have returned I want to run another function.

Currently I have it working by delaying the final function 1 second but I would really like to get Dispatch Group working.

I've been through various online examples and other questions but nothing I try seems to work, The code I have at the moment I know won't work as it is running dispatchGroup.leave() each time the for in functions are sent rather than when they return.

I've tried puting the DispatchGroup code in the function (which is in another file) but I'm stumped, however I think I am close to a solution.

I've also looked at semaphores and using count and incrementing a value each time the loop runs but I keep coming back to DispatchGroups.

My last resort is to ask a question!

ViewController code

```
 @IBAction func removeDeviceBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for owner in arrOwnerList {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        self.removeDevice(device: self.device, account: owner as! String, completion: self.completed)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        self.removeDeviceFromServer(device: self.device)
        self.sendEmail(to:"gordon@example.co.uk", subject:self.device+" has been removed", text:self.device+" has been removed from the server, please check the sim for bar and termination")
    })
```

Function code in other file as an extension

```
  func completed(isSuccess: Bool) {
}

func removeDevice(device: String, account: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let dictHeader : [String:String] = ["username":Username,"password":Password]
    let dictArray = [device]

    WebHelper.requestPUTAPIRemoveDevice(BaseURL+"rootaccount/removedevices/"+account+"?server=MUIR", header: dictHeader, dictArray: dictArray, controllerView: self, success: { (response) in
        if response.count == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: GlobalConstant.AppName, andMessage: Messages.ServerError, on: self)
            }
        }
        else {
            if response.count != 0 {
                let isSuccess = true
                completion(isSuccess)
            }
            else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: GlobalConstant.AppName, andMessage: Messages.NoDataFound, on: self)

                }
            }
        }
    }) { (error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: GlobalConstant.AppName, andMessage: error?.localizedDescription ?? Messages.ServerError, on: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Code from WebHelper file

```
    class func requestPUTAPIRemoveDevice(_ strURL: String,header: Dictionary<String,String>,dictArray: Array<Any>, controllerView viewController: UIViewController, success: @escaping (_ response: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void, failure: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    if GlobalConstant.isReachable() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            LoadingIndicatorView.sharedInstance.showHUD()
        }
        let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", header["username"]!, header["password"]!)
        let loginData: Data = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())

        let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic "+base64LoginString, "Referer": "http://www.example.com"]

        let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictArray, options: [])

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: strURL)! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    LoadingIndicatorView.sharedInstance.hideHUD()
                }
                failure(error)
            } else {
                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("Server code \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 || httpResponse.statusCode == 208 {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            LoadingIndicatorView.sharedInstance.hideHUD()
                        }
                        let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:    JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)

                        if (jsonResult is NSDictionary) {
                            success(jsonResult as! [AnyHashable : Any])
                        }
                        else if (jsonResult is NSArray) {
                            success(["response":jsonResult as! NSArray])
                        }
                        else{
                          success(["response":httpResponse.statusCode])
                          DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        }

                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            LoadingIndicatorView.sharedInstance.hideHUD()
                        }
                        failure(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
    else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            LoadingIndicatorView.sharedInstance.hideHUD()
            GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: "", andMessage: "Internet not connected", on: viewController)
        }

    }
}
```

The final solution (apart from tidying up the various other issues) was to add `success(["response":httpResponse.statusCode])` to the WebHelper file, corrected code above

Comment: `dispatchGroup.leave()` needs to be in the completion handler.

Comment: Does that mean it should be in the completed function or where I check the response count is != 0

Comment: Do you understand what asynchronous means? You want to “leave” when your web helper request has finished. But you are saying “leave” before your web helper request can even get started.

Comment: By the way, calling `completed` after each one is curious. Out of curiosity, what are you doing in `completed`?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what I am calling `completed` for, all I need to do is fire off each API call and when they all return then run the final function. It's possible I am going about this all wrong!

Comment: If you’re not doing anything in that routine, I’d excise it from the code entirely.

Comment: Unrelated, as a matter of convention, I’d suggest avoiding property names with uppercase letter. E.g. we’d use `username` and `password` rather than `Username` and `Password`. Also, the use of the forced unwrapping pattern (e.g. `owner as! String`) is generally not advised. That will crash if `owner` was `nil` or if the cast failed. You might use a `guard let owner = owner as? String else { ... }` pattern, or something like that. It’s hard to say on the basis of the information provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `leave` inside the completion handler:

```
for owner in arrOwnerList {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    removeDevice(device: device, account: owner as! String) { [weak self] success in
        self?.completed(isSuccess: success)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}
```

Or given that you’re not really doing anything in `completed` function, I’d just remove that:

```
for owner in arrOwnerList {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    removeDevice(device: device, account: owner as! String) { _ in
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}
```

---

I notice that you have paths of execution in `removeDevice` that aren’t calling the completion handler. Make sure every path of execution calls the completion handler or else your dispatch group will never get resolved.

```
func removeDevice(device: String, account: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let dictHeader = ["username": Username, "password": Password]
    let dictArray = [device]

    WebHelper.requestPUTAPIRemoveDevice(BaseURL+"rootaccount/removedevices/"+account+"?server=MUIR", header: dictHeader, dictArray: dictArray, controllerView: self, success: { response in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if response.count == 0 {
                GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: GlobalConstant.AppName, andMessage: Messages.ServerError, on: self)
                completion(false)
            } else {
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    }, failure: { error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: GlobalConstant.AppName, andMessage: error?.localizedDescription ?? Messages.ServerError, on: self)
            completion(false)
        }
    })
}
```

By the way, I don’t know the name of the “failure” closure, so I assumed it was `failure`, but adjust as required by your `requestPUTAPIRemoveDevice` method. We generally avoid the multiple closure pattern in Swift, but if you’re going to do that, I’d avoid the trailing closure syntax. It makes the functional intent of this second closure a bit more explicit.

Or, this all begs the question as to why `requestPUTAPIRemoveDevice` is initiating UI updates at all. I’d probably put that in the view controller method. So `requestPUTAPIRemoveDevice` should just pass back enough information so the `removeDeviceBtn` routines knows what error to present. And this idea of presenting a separate error message for each failure is probably suspect, too. (E.g. if you have lost internet connection and are trying to remove a dozen devices, do you really want to show a dozen separate error messages?) But this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I am getting the following error:    Contextual closure type '(Bool) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 0 were used in closure body

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that you had a parameter there. I revised to show how you’d use that (or just remove it entirely).

Comment: The for in loop functions (3 on my test) worked fine but the final function in the dispatchGroup.notify didn't run. It didn't fail, it didn't run at all.  Is there something obvious causing it?   The only warning in the code is:   Variable 'self' was written to, but never read

Comment: The “Variable ‘self’ was written to, but never read” is just telling you that the `[weak self]` is not needed if the closure doesn’t refer to `self`. I’ve removed that above. If the dispatch group `notify` is not called, that means that one or more of the `enter` calls was not balanced with a corresponding `leave` call. That could happen because your `requestPUTAPIRemoveDevice` had paths of execution where you weren’t calling the completion handler. You must always call the completion handler. I’ve tried to show what `requestPUTAPIRemoveDevice` might look like.

Comment: thanks for your help, it appears I've got more issues than I thought, best I go back and investigate your comments and develop new code.